# Setting turtle colour

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to ask "Choose your pen colour(red, orange, yellow, green or blue): "
and change turtle pen colour according to their choices. And this are my lines so far:

```
    colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"]
    color = input ("Please choose your color (red, orange, yellow, green, blue): ")
    color = choice.colors
    turtle.color (color)
```

system says "choice" is not defined. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `random.choice()` function is used when you want the computer to randomly choose a color.  Since you're letting your user decide, we don't need it:

```
import turtle

COLORS = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']

color = input("Please choose your color ({}): ".format(', '.join(COLORS)))

turtle.color(color)

turtle.done()
```